# Iterate argument only one time in for loop (Python)

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I have the following "problem", more a question in fact: it is possible to execute an argument in a for loop just one time per cycle ?

I have a code which is something like the following:

```
count = 0    

for a in b:
        #do something

    if not y:
        #do something
    else:
        code=(c,d,e)

count += 1
```

Please, try to understand, is more a theoretical question than a practical one.

It is possible to iterate `c` just one time and the other (`d,e`) as far as loop have to be done, maintaining the above schema ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what you are asking. What is `c`? Do you want to execute the `code=...` line just once per loop? What if the `else` is hit again? No-operation, or do you want to stop the loop entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to determine the order in loop.

Example:

```
for k, a in enumerate(b):
    #do something
    if not y:
        #do something
    else:
        code = ((c, d, e) if k == 0 else (d, e))
```

Comment: It seems to work...